Does it matter where we get sets from in $\mathsf{ZFC}$?
Suppose I was working with some given set $X$ in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and for some reason I wanted to do something like "add 3 constants/atoms/new elements (whatever may be the case)" to this set, or even "add a countably infinite amount of new constants $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n$ to the set $X$" (not found in $X$ already, of course). Can I just add these such constants/new members without specifying how they may be constructed/where they may come from? For any particular set $X$, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ clearly proves the existence of sets that are not elements of $X$ (and this for any arbitrary amount of such sets we may want, lest we have something akin to a set universe). So... it should be fine to just "add new constants" out of nowhere?

Yes, that's fine. Formally you can pick a construction of the disjoint union.

Is it? I thought new sets could only be built by using the ZFC axioms.

The axiom of Foundation proves that ${X}, {{X}}, \ldots$ are not elements of $X$.  This suffices for a finite family of constants that are not element of $X$.  For a countably infinite family, one could take $\langle n, X\rangle$ where $n$ is a Von Neumann ordinal and  $\langle\cdots\rangle$ is the usual Kuratowski ordered pair.

It depends on exactly how formal you want to be, but the result which makes all of this "sweep-under-the-rug-able" is the following:

(In ZF, or indeed vastly less) For any sets $X,Y$ there is a set $X'$ such that $X\equiv X'$ and $X'\cap Y=\emptyset$.

Here "$\equiv$" denotes "is equinumerous with" - in the absence of choice, this is a little nicer than the "$\vert...\vert$"-notation in my opinion.
The proof of the above fact is quite easy, and is a good exercise:

 Let $X'=X\times\{Y\}$ and use Foundation/Regularity.


I have actually seen a construction of the one-point compactification of topological space $X$ in which the writer felt it was necessary to specify that the "new point" could be taken to be $X$ itself, since $X\notin X$ so $X$ is certainly not already a point.  J.H. Conway has lamented that ZFC has become so entrenched that people expect this sort of justification.

@MJD I don't love the gratuitous use of regularity here. Better make it the least ordinal not in $X$ :)

Actually, can the theorem in this answer be proven without choice or replacement or regularity (and if so is there a definable class function that does this)? (Not that it affects the upshot, really… we can always make a copy of $Y$  too.)

The result is actually provable even without foundation, though. Take $X'=X\times{\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ is the least ordinal such that $X\times{\alpha}\bigcap Y=\varnothing$ (such an $\alpha$ must exist; o/w use replacement to get a "set" of all ordinals)

@spaceisdarkgreen I do believe that replacement is essential here, since otherwise you will have a hard time showing $X$ and $X'$ are equinumerous...
